# Hive: Data validation / bad data handling?

Tags: validation, hadoop, hive

When bringing in "outside" data into Hive, what is the best way to validate that it is "clean"?  We don't want any invalid values to get into our Hive table.

For example, if a field in the source data is supposed to contain a valid date but the format is incorrect (example: An "I" was entered by human user instead of a one), how do we detect this?

So we have `20I5-06-09` in the source data instead of `2015-06-09`.

Even more tricky, what if the format is OK but it isn't a valid date; for example the source data contains `2015-02-30` but we don't want to let that in because February can't have 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

You could validate use Hive's inbuilt function `to_date` which will return `NULL` on your first kind of bad data:

```
hive> select to_date('2015-02-02'),to_date('20I5-02-02');

2015-02-02      NULL
```

For your second kind of bad data it does something else interesting though ... I think this maybe should be raised as a bug.

```
hive> select to_date('2015-02-30');

2015-03-02
```

To get around this issue you could do

```
    select case when datecol = to_date(datecol) then datecol end
```

Answer (score 0):

We typically scrub/validate our data before putting it into a Hive table.  Any scripting languages would be quick to write and any of the following methods would work:

1. Validate the data before pushing it to HDFS.
2. If the data is already on HDFS, run a MapReduce job against it filtering out or fixing any bad entries.  Then load into Hive.  All this could be automated using Oozie.

Comment: So you would recommend using something other than Hive itself for data validation?  I considered using shell scripting + awk because I have lots of experience with those.  I also have Java experience so that would be another option.  The reason for my original question is that management requested "Hive only" for this project.  However, if Hive is really not well suited to the validation process then we can advise them that this is not recommended.